# how can i make my Link dynamic in react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to login only when isLoggedIn is True, else it will be in the "/login".
if isLoggedIn is True it should go to "/device"

I tried using the ternary operator but it not working, how can I use the Link to move different pages dynamically

Comment: The initial state of `isLoggedIn` is false, so the only way for it to become true is to click the link and make the asynchronous request. What do you expect the UI to do at this point? What is the scenario where this component is mounted and `this.state.isLoggedIn` is true *before* the user clicks the link to navigate?

Comment: user will click on Link, and it will run that function, then the value of isLoggeIn become true, so it should go to "/devices" and if after clicking the value of isLoggedIn is still false it will go to "/login" means the same page
or is there any other way to do it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I'm understanding your question correctly, you want a user to be able to click a "login" link and make a POST request to the "/api/userCheck" endpoint. Depending on the response you want to conditionally navigate to either "/devices" or to "/login" (*stay on the same page*).

For this you will need to prevent the default "action" of clicking the link from triggering the navigation and call the `handleLoginClick` callback, then issue an imperative navigation to the target route.

```
handleLoginClick(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  const { pass, user } = this.state;

  axios.post(
    "http://localhost:3001/api/userCheck",
    { email: user, password: pass }
  ).then(res => {
      if (res.data.login) {
        this.setState({ fname: res.data.fname });
        this.setState({ isLoggedIn: true });
        localStorage.setItem('loginstatus', true);
        this.props.history.replace("/device");
      } else {
        this.setState({ isLoggedIn: false });
        this.props.history.replace("/login");
      }
    }).catch(err => {
      this.setState({ isLoggedIn: false });
      this.props.history.replace("/login");
    });
}
```

Ensure the click event is passed to the callback.

```
<Link
  onClick={this.handleLoginClick} // <-- set handleLoginClick directly as callback
  to="/devices"
  className="btn btn-pink my-3"
>
  <i className="fas fa-lock"/>
  Login
</Link>
```